# Optional token for group seems to prevent capture?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to capture the text between the brackets of X{} and Y{}:

```
echo "example ,X{whateverX},...,Y{whateverY} the end" | \
  perl -ne 'print "$2 $4 \n" if /.*(,X\{(.*?)\}).*(,Y\{(.*?)\})/;' 
whateverX whateverY
```

Now, I want to make the presence of X and/or Y optional, but as soon as I add the optional modifier it stops matching/capturing:

```
echo "example ,X{whateverX},...,Y{whateverY} the end" | \
      perl -ne 'print "$2 $4 \n" if /.*(,X\{(.*?)\})?.*(,Y\{(.*?)\})?/;' 
<nothing printed>
```

NOTE: above I added the ? modifier at the and of each of the X/Y groups as highlighted below (last character):

```
.\*(,X\\{(.\*?)\\})**?**

.\*(,Y\\{(.\*?)\\})**?**
```

For instance, here I only have Y as optional and only X is matched:

```
echo "example ,X{whateverX},...,Y{whateverY} the end" | \
      perl -ne 'print "$2 $4 \n" if /.*(,X\{(.*?)\}).*(,Y\{(.*?)\})?/;'
whateverX
```

I expected all three to produce "whateverX whateverY" but only the first one does...

What am I missing? Why does making the capture-group optional break my matching?

Comment: Is perl a requirement?

Comment: Does the order matter?  For example, if Y came before X, would it mess you up if it still captured?  I was thinking `my @matches = $example =~ /[XY]\{([^}]+)\}/g;`  Also this would capture multiple occurrences of X and Y.

Comment: Provide more samples of input with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remind yourself of the basic facet of regular expressions: they're greedy by default as long as the entire expression can match.

Your example of

```
/.*(,X\{(.*?)\})?.*(,Y\{(.*?)\})?/
```

only has optional elements, so it will always match - an empty string if nothing else.

Problem is, RE will be greedy at the earliest possible position and to the greatest extent possible (while still being able to match the rest of the expression). Therefore the first `.*` will consume everything in your string, leaving the other subexpressions to default to matching empty strings (via `?` or `*`).

It's hard to make the X{} and Y{} optional while still preferring them to be present; If you make them optional, the regex engine will end up never using them if it can get away with it.

I'd suggest using subexpressions with alternating combinations of X{} and Y{} present either inside `(?:...|...)` (with subsequent assignment of values to variables depending on the branch used) or inside branch reset `(?|...|...)` (written as proper code in order to use the `/x`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $data (<DATA>) {
    chomp $data;

    if ($data =~ /
                     (?|
                         .*?                  # both X and Y present
                         ,X \{ ([^{}]*) \}
                         .*?
                         ,Y \{ ([^{}]*) \}
                     |
                         .*?                  # only X present
                         ,X \{ ([^{}]*) \}
                         .*
                         ()
                     |
                         .*?                  # only Y present
                         ()
                         ,Y \{ ([^{}]*) \}
                     |                
                         () ()                # neither X nor Y present
                     )
                 /x) {

        print "$1, $2\n";
    }
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
example ,X{whateverX},...,Y{whateverY} the end
example2 ,X{whateverX2},random data to the end
example3 with data before ,Y{whateverY3} the end
example4 with just data and no separators
```

Will output:

```
whateverX, whateverY
whateverX2, 
, whateverY3
,
```

Note that the leading `.*?`'s are needed, or otherwise the `()()` would end up matching in each case.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. I was intent to get it to work with one pattern but now I understand why multiple patterns is the only way to go.

Comment: Nice use of /x modifier (ignore whitespace) to make the regex readable

Answer (score 0):

Specially because your second group is optional, you need to make sure that your middle discard match the .* in the middle doesn't match with the start of your second block:

```
echo "example ,X{whateverX},...,Y{whateverY} the end" | \
perl -ne 'print "$2 $4 \n" if /.*(,X\{(.*?)\})(?:(?!,Y).)*(,Y\{(.*?)\})?/;'
whateverX whateverY
```

The important bit in there is this:

```
(?:(?!,Y).)*
```

the (?: ) makes sure this is not a capture group

the (?!,Y) makes sure that this block does not include the string ,Y

If you want to be more precise, you can use (?!,Y{) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another, arguably much simpler approach: let the engine do more than one match per line with the global modifier.   Your pattern then becomes a trivial alternation,  without all the `.*` or `?` shenanigans:

`/X\{(?<X>.*?)\}|Y\{(?<Y>.*?)\}/g`

[regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/lIfCKh/2/)